# Drop-in replacement for nodejs request on Parse.com cloud code?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Im trying to use the [TumblrJS API](https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.js) on Parse Cloud code however it requires "require" which is a nodejs package and Parse.com has its own HTTPRequest process.

I was wondering if anyone has come up with a simple drop-in replacement for request for parse.com such as the "[browser-request](https://www.npmjs.org/package/browser-request)" library?

Cheers,
Mike